# JDK11 getFreeSpace and getTotalSpace from File is not matching df

Tags: java, linux, java-11

I am seeing `df -h` giving output like below

```
root@vrni-platform:/var/lib# df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-var            110G   94G   11G  91% /var
```

```
root@vrni-platform:/var/lib# df -k
Filesystem                   1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-var           114756168 98318504  10585300  91% /var
```

But if I do the same from java like below

````java
final File dataPath = new File("/var");
final long totalBytes = dataPath.getTotalSpace();
final long usedBytes = totalBytes - dataPath.getFreeSpace();
System.out.printf("Disk utilization: %.2f, Total bytes: %d, Used Bytes: %d", ((double)usedBytes/totalBytes * 100), totalBytes, usedBytes);```
````

It is printing like below

```
Disk utilization: 85.68, Total bytes: 117510316032, Used Bytes: 100678909952
```

Can someone let me know why is this discrepancy in disk utilization?

Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Java - Zulu OpenJDK 11.0.11

Comment: I removed your second question, as it would make your question 'not focussed'. If you want to know how to use ProcessBuilder, search for existing questions that - I think - should already cover that, or failing that, ask a new and separate question about that, demonstrating what you already tried and how that didn't work.

Comment: Also, exactly what discrepancy are you looking for to be explained? For example, total bytes matches just fine (114756168 * 1024 = 117.510.316.032), used doesn't, which might be the difference between reported file sizes and number of 1K blocks used for those files (at a guess).

Comment: Updated the question. I meant the discrepancy in disk utilisation. `df` is showing 91% Use and if I calculate it via `getTotalSpace` and `getFreeSpace` in java it is coming around 86%

Comment: Both sets of numbers produce the same ratio but `df` prints something other than 98318504/114756168*100. The source code for `df` is where you'll find your answer.

Comment: I agree with Jeff Holt, 98318504 / 114756168 (df numbers) = 85,68% as well, so apparently it uses a different derivation of percentage used than straight division of those numbers (maybe it considers additional overheads, etc of the file system?)

Comment: Looking at the numbers, `df` uses '(total - available) / total', which results in 91%, which suggests that `getFreeSpace()` reports something else than DFs 'Available', DFs Used + Available is less than 1K-blocks (as is Used + Avail less than Size for the first command). I guess you would be better off asking this question on a Linux / Unix stack.

Comment: Ok, I have added `linux` as one of the tags though.

Comment: I was more thinking of https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Agreed. This question, why are the two ratios not the same is now answered. The "why" part is off-topic for SO but not off-topic for the SE site you cited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I also mentioned in the comments, the primary reason is that `getFreeSpace` seems to report something else than DFs 'Avail' or 'Available'. Going by DFs '1K-blocks' and 'Used', you also get a percentage of 85,68%, while going by '1K-blocks' and 'Available' yields 91%. Also observe how DFs 'Used' and 'Available' (and 'Used' and 'Avail') do not add up to '1K-blocks' (or 'Size')

As suggested by [user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675), using `getUsableSpace` might be a better method to use than `getFreeSpace`. As to the reasons for the difference between '1K-blocks' - 'Used' and 'Available' in `df`, it might be better to ask that on https://unix.stackexchange.com/.